# (Australia) Conjoint senior lecturer? Do they teach?

Tags: terminology, lecturer, australia

In Australia, I see many non-university researchers (e.g. CSIRO postdocs) have a title of "conjoint lecturer" from a reputable university.

- Do they teach?
- Do they receive salary from the university?
- What's the point of the title if everybody who is a postdoc in Australia can be a  "lecturer"?

Comment: Whether they teach or supervise student is negotiable and is at the discretion of the head of school.  Usually they volunteer.  The main point is to get a foot in the door of the university in question or to get some teaching experience.  Also, the university may have a policy that says who can and cannot supervise a PhD student. By having a formal appointment, then the CSIRO post-doc has the same privileges as an academic staff.   They may receive salary from the university if the post-doc position is funded by both university and CSIRO.  Otherwise, CSIRO is providing it as an 'in-kind'.

Comment: "What's the point of the title if everybody who is a postdoc in Australia can be a "lecturer"?"    That's not true.  Postdocs are usually at the rank and pay of an "associate lecturer" level A and they usually have a different title.  A lecturer is level B and is paid a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to hold a senior position in a Group of Eight university in Australia. At my old university, conjoint appointments ranged from Lecturer (Level B) to Professor (Level E). Conjoint appointments were not allowed at Associate Lecturer (Level A) level.

In return for the appointment, conjoints were expected to fill roles as negotiated by the Head of Department. They were paid a specific rate for their time, but this was NOT a regular salary; they were contractual employees. Some provided lectures or workshops or seminars, others were tutors, yet others supervised students on placement, others were "prestige" conjoints who featured on websites and other marketing material like prized chooks on display.

All conjoints received an email account, library access, facilities access (such as the gym or childcare), and (perhaps most importantly) has some limited parking privileges.

I hope this helps.

*Edited to correct pesky typos.